# Speed up parser: HTML into Database

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need insert all html tags and attributes into database

```
el.driver.get(url_page)
txthtml = el.driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(txthtml, "html.parser")
body = soup.find('html')
html_parse(body, el, url_page_id, 0, 0, 0,url_page)

def html_parse(html, el, url_page_id, level, i, parent_id, url_page):
    txt = ""
    if len(html.text) > 0:
       txt = html.text.replace("\n","").replace("\t","").replace("\r","")
    ta = tag_list()
    ta.p_id = el.id
    ta.page_id = url_page_id
    ta.level = level
    ta.number = i
    ta.txt = txt
    ta.name = html.name
    ta.parent_id = parent_id
    ta.html = str(html)
    ta.save()
    insert_attr(html, el.id, url_page_id, ta.id, url_page)
    children = list(html.children)
    j = 0
    for child in children:
        if child.name is None:
            continue
        j = j + 1
        html_parse(child, el, url_page_id, level + 1, j, ta.id, url_page)
```

When I have recursive function html_parse

- html -  current html object
- el - driver class
- url_page_id - id of page
- level - level in DOM
- i - childe number
- parent_id - id of parent
- url_page - current URL
- tag_list - insert current tag
- insert_attr - insert into database attrs of tag

Every html_parse function run fast, but full html parsing run about 4-5 minutes per big html page.

How I can speed up the code?

Comment: What is your question? Half of it suggests that you're having trouble inserting values into a database, but there's none in the question, and the other half asks how to speed up your code.

Comment: speed up the code